# CSV file not found even though it exists (FileNotFound [Errno 2])

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, spyder

I was trying to read a dataset but I'm getting this weird error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Position_Salaries.csv' does not exist: b'Position_Salaries.csv'
```

Even though the file does exist and its on the same directory of my code ([As you can see in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lVg1.png))

The weird thing is, I've run that code many times without getting any kind of error, but suddenly (without changing anything)is not working. I literally just opened Spyder, try to run the code, but nope, that error appeared. Any ideas why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Part of the code I'm trying to run:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values 
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
```

Comment: Are you sure your working directory in your IDE is correct? Try running it through command line

Comment: You must have `.csv` file and `.py` script in same directory. do `print(__file__)` to see what path of file is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool tip that is obscuring your picture but from the information provided I would guess that your working directory is not set to your project directory. Try running the code from the terminal.

Comment: Jesus Christ, it was that. Im getting the impostor syndrome. Anyway, thank you so much. Solved!

Comment: @ArmsMG No worries! It happens all the time! I would highly recommend using an IDE like pycharm if you are looking to avoid some of the small mistakes that make you scratch your head like this.

Also please accept my answer if this solved your problem :)

Comment: I'll have this in mind, many people have told me that PyCharm is the best IDE for python, but anyways, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens due to the changes in the format of your excel file. Make sure that the excel file is saved as CVS.